# How i Use the transaction for operation of DB and File IO?

Tags: c#, file, transactions, io, transactionscope

**Preface**

I have a table that contains information about the user, that  One of the it fields is *AvatarUrl* that consist of user uploaded avatar url.

[image: User Table]

I Need to Transaction to Track Change in DataBase and File IO.For example, when you delete a user record AvatarUrl is located opposite the user to delete. Therefore I am using the transaction.Is Exist any Command  to follow the changes in the database and File IO.My Development environment Is C#.net and my DB is SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Nobody is going to answer when you have a 0% acceptance record pal.

Comment: have you tried typing the tags "c# file transactions io transactionscope" into google?

Comment: @Derek In My question don't matter that The DB is Implemented right or wrong.Yes I know that the file can be stored in the database as binary string or binary format.  The important question is whether to we be able to do it or not?

Comment: @paul before I debate this question I not found anythings that be useful.